# Change data type of excel Cell using Aspose?

Tags: c#, .net, aspose, aspose-cells

We are to show data with Currency symbol ("TRL") in Excel cell with Currency type and we write the excel cell using this data "TRL 100.00" then that cell automatically converted in to General type instead of Currency type although we have changed the format of the particular cell using (styleFlag's property NumberFormat=true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following sample code, its comments and the **screenshot showing the output Excel file**. The code first formats the **cell A1** with **TRL currency format**. Then it formats the **entire column C** with **TRL currency format**.

**C#**

```
//Create workbook
Workbook wb = new Workbook();

//Access first worksheet
Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[0];

//Add some value in cell A1
Cell cell = ws.Cells["A1"];
cell.PutValue(22);

//Format cell A1 with TRL formatting
Style st = cell.GetStyle();
st.Custom = "[$TRL]\\ #,##0.00";
cell.SetStyle(st);

//Make the entire column C with TRL formatting
StyleFlag flg = new StyleFlag();
flg.NumberFormat = true;
ws.Cells.Columns[2].ApplyStyle(st, flg);

//Now enter data in column C cells
ws.Cells["C5"].PutValue(31);
ws.Cells["C6"].PutValue(32);
ws.Cells["C7"].PutValue(33);
ws.Cells["C8"].PutValue(34);

//Save the workbook
wb.Save("output.xlsx");
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Update - I**

Screenshot showing the result of this following line.

```
st.Custom = "[$฿-41E]#,##0.00";
```

[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: sorry for the late response, it worked for "TRL" but not for "kr" currency could you please help me on this

Comment: Please do the following change in the above code. i.e. ---------- st.Custom = "[$TRL]\\ #,##0.00"; --- to ---- st.Custom = "[$SEK]\\ #,##0.00"; --- and it will fix your issue. Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for your support, but i am facing another issue, everything is working fine except "Thai Baht" symbol is not showing in cell instead of showing "฿1000", I am getting "1000" in cell (Cell Font=Arial) but when i changed the font then it showed me correct value.

Comment: Please do the following change in the above code. i.e. ---- st.Custom = "[$TRL]\\ #,##0.00"; ---- to ---- st.Custom = "[$฿-41E]#,##0.00"; ---- and it will fix your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is not working; Still symbol is there but user can not see that symbol, it is visible only when I Change the Cell font from "Arial" to "Calibri"

Comment: The line is working fine even in Arial. Please see the new screenshot that I have added inside the reply for your reference.

Comment: Again thanks for you reply, actual issue was that Cell had "wrapped Text" so it was not showing.

Answer (score 0):

Most easy way is set style number for the cells.

```
//$1,234.56
ws.Cells[1,1].Value = 1234.56;
var style=ws.Cells[1.1].GetStyle();
style.Number=5; // 5 is build-in style for currency
ws.Cells[1,1].SetStyle(style);
```

You can find all build-in styles here: https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/list-of-supported-number-formats/